# how to control size of scrollable <div> AND lock copyright notice at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, scroll, height

I'm manually coding a fairly simple website, using just HTML and CSS.  For one particular page, I want the following layout:  my standard navigation bar at the top (implemented as a table), immediately followed by an article title (another table), immediately followed by a text area (implemented as a div), followed by my standard copyright notice at the very bottom of the page (yet another table).  The text area will contain just plain text, divided into paragraphs with p and /p tags and lightly formatted with b and /b tags.  The text area also has some special requirements:  (1) it must display a vertical scroll bar whenever it is too small to display all the text it contains; (2) it must never be shorter than a stated number of pixels (200 for example); and (3) subject to that minimum it must automatically increase its vertical size as much as possible PROVIDED that (a) it is never taller than required to display the entire contents of the text area and (b) it is never taller than the available space in the browser window (i.e., the vertical space available between the navigation bar and article title on top and the copyright notice on the bottom).

The code I'm using is below.  I've tried switching things around many different ways, and am about to tear my hair out - no matter what I do the best I can get is the navigation bar and article title appearing as they should, but the text area getting mysteriously set to some apparently arbitrary vertical size, and the copyright notice appearing immediately below the text area instead of hugging the bottom of the page as it should.  While this is the only page that needs the scrollable text area, the same copyright code works exactly as intended on all the other pages of the site.

I'd be really grateful for any suggestions about how to resolve this.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  background: url(images/CrossHatch.jpg);
    font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
  color: #7777ff;
}

h2 {
  color: #7777ff;
}

.navigation {
  font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.linkname {
  font-size: small;
}

.linktext {
  font-size: small;
}

.copyright {
  font-size: xx-small;
}

.articlebox {
  overflow: auto;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: FFFFFF;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0%;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.f1 {
  font-size: xx-small;
}

.f2 {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.f3 {
  font-size: small;
}

.f4 {
  font-size: medium;
}

.f5 {
  font-size: large;
}

.f6 {
  font-size: x-large;
}

.f7 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.articletitle {
  font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.articlerevised {
  font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div height="100%">

  <table border="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="d7d7d7" width="100%">
    <tbody align="center" valign="middle">
      <!-- tr and td tags go here to implement navigation bar -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="75%"><span class="articletitle">This is the article title</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td height="10px"><td></tr>
  </table>

  <div class="articlebox">
    <!-- scrollable article text goes here -->
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam in. Sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet. Tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut. Duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida.
    </p>
    <p>
    Nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Cras sed felis eget velit. Euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut. Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div valign="bottom">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td><font size="1"><b>[standard copyright boilerplate]</b></font></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look up how to write valid HTML. Your HTML has so many errors, it is written like it is the year 1990. I would advise you to remove all tables and all font-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.articlebox {
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

You can choose between 150 and 200.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry, but that doesn't work either.  When I add the attributes you specified to the existing ones in the .articlebox class, I get the same result as before except that the text area is now even larger than before.  When I replace the existing attributes with the ones you specified, the entire box disappears and the text it contains appears just like any other text on the page.

Comment: try new code (I have edit..)

Comment: That doesn't work either.  I'm going to change directions and just go with a fixed height box.  Thanks for the suggestions.